# «Программист (—) и за городом программист». Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Сомневаюсь, что нужно его ставить. Подскажите, какое здесь действует правило?

А также интересует пунктуация в "расширенном" варианте этой фразы: "Программист () он и за городом () программист".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***Программист и за городом  программист.***

В этом предложении ***и*** является не союзом, а частицей.

Тире не ставится, паузы нет.

Данное предложение можно перефразировать так: *Программист **даже за городом** программист . Программист **везде** программист.*  В этих предложениях тире также не ставится.

В правилах Розенталя есть такой пункт:

Примечание. Обычно тире не ставится:

5) если перед сказуемым стоит **относящийся к нему второстепенный член  предложения**: Степан нам сосед (Ш.); Коля мне друг;

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Речь в данном случае идет **об обстоятельстве или дополнении**, которое относится ко всему предложению, а не входит в группу подлежащего или сказуемого, например:

*Необдуманный поступок **вообще** шаг опасный. Литература **всегда** учебник жизни. Это спокойствие **часто** признак великой, хотя скрытой силы. Туризм **для меня** лучший отдых. Отец **у меня** золотой человек.*

2. ***Программист, он и за городом программист.***

Это предложение **с именительным темы.**

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63

Пример из правила: ***Врач***, он ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.);